# Pact exact match of a field within an array

Tags: pact

I am writing a pact test for a request that filters out the response data by a certain field, hense I would like to create a matcher that would match an array of objects with an exact match on that field.

I tried doing the following two aproaches:

```
body: eachLike({
  color: 'red',
  name: like('any'),
}),

body: eachLike({
  color: extractPayload('red'),
  name: like('any'),
}),
```

Bot both of them produce the same result:

```
"matchingRules": {
  "$.body": {
    "min": 1
  },
  "$.body[*].*": {
    "match": "type"
  },
  "$.body[*].name": {
    "match": "type"
  }
}
```

It seems to me that having `"$.body[*].*": {"match": "type"}` in there negates the exact matching for the `color` field. Am I wrong in that assumption, or is there a correct approach that would resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that the `type` matching is cascading and is not being reset.

The `equal` matcher (V3 only) will reset the matching rule for this context.

It's available in the latest beta: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/feat/v3.0.0#using-the-v3-matching-rules

To work it in v2, I would use the `regex` that matches a single string value here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, too bad the js version is still stuck in v2, will be waiting with baited breath for the new release.

Comment: Hopefully only a couple of months away now